# Large one-to-many select query optimization via LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

New to FNH and NH.

I'd like to optimize a query for a OneToMany mapping. I'd actually like to only retrieve one of the many where Segment = 0. PlantID,AreaID,CellID,DeviceID,StartDateTime make up the composite primary key for Data. Add Segment to composite key for DataMore1 and DataMore2.

An event can record up to 400 data points...depending on the options they have chosen.
So we've elected to store the data in separate tables for purging of unwanted data after x days or months.

The goal is to do something like this via FluentNHibernate.

```
SELECT        Data.PlantID, Data.AreaID, Data.CellID, Data.DeviceID, Data.StartDateTime, Data.DataPoint01, DataMore1.Segment, DataMore1.DataPoint101, 
                         DataMore2.DataPoint201
FROM            Data 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         DataMore1 ON Data.PlantID = DataMore1.PlantID AND Data.AreaID = DataMore1.AreaID AND Data.CellID = DataMore1.CellID AND 
                         Data.DeviceID = DataMore1.DeviceID AND Data.StartDateTime = DataMore1.StartDateTime AND **DataMore1.Segment = 0** 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         DataMore2 ON Data.PlantID = DataMore2.PlantID AND Data.AreaID = DataMore2.AreaID AND Data.CellID = DataMore2.CellID AND 
                         Data.DeviceID = DataMore2.DeviceID AND Data.StartDateTime = DataMore2.StartDateTime AND **DataMore2.Segment = 0**
```

**The MODEL**

```
public class Data
{
        public virtual int PlantID { get; set; }
        public virtual int AreaID { get; set; }
        public virtual int CellID { get; set; }
        public virtual int DeviceID { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint01 { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint02 { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint99 { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<DataMore1> DataMore1 { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<DataMore2> DataMore2 { get; set; }
}

public class DataMore1
{
        public virtual int PlantID { get; set; }
        public virtual int AreaID { get; set; }
        public virtual int CellID { get; set; }
        public virtual int DeviceID { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual byte Segment { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint101 { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint102 { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint199 { get; set;}
}

public class DataMore2
{
        public virtual int PlantID { get; set; }
        public virtual int AreaID { get; set; }
        public virtual int CellID { get; set; }
        public virtual int DeviceID { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual byte Segment { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint201 { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint202 { get; set; }
        public virtual float DataPoint299 { get; set; }
}
```

**And the MAPPINGS**

```
  public DataMap()
 {
   Table("Data");
        CompositeId()
    .KeyProperty(e => e.PlantID)
    .KeyProperty(e => e.AreaID)
    .KeyProperty(e => e.CellID)
    .KeyProperty(e => e.DeviceID)
            .KeyProperty(e => e.StartDateTime);
        Map(e => e.DataPoint01);
        Map(e => e.DataPoint02);
        Map(e => e.DataPoint99);
        HasMany(e => e.DataMore1)
            .KeyColumns.Add("PlantID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("AreaID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("CellID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("DeviceID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("StartDateTime")
            .Cascade.All().Inverse();
        HasMany(e => e.DataMore2)
            .KeyColumns.Add("PlantID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("AreaID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("CellID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("DeviceID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("StartDateTime")
            .Cascade.All().Inverse();
}

public DataMore1Map()
{
    Table("DataMore1");
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(e => e.PlantID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.AreaID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.CellID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.DeviceID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.StartDateTime)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.Segment);
    Map(e => e.DataPoint101);
    Map(e => e.DataPoint102);
    Map(e => e.DataPoint199);
}

public DataMore2Map()
{
    Table("DataMore2");
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(e => e.PlantID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.AreaID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.CellID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.DeviceID)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.StartDateTime)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.Segment);
    Map(e => e.DataPoint201);
    Map(e => e.DataPoint202);
    Map(e => e.DataPoint299);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a query question?

Since you are new to NH I give a bit wider answer than required. The first two classes should answer your question in their own.

```
public class DataQuery : AbstractQueryObject<IList<DataQueryResult>>
{
    public override IList<DataQueryResult> GetResult()
    {
        DataMore1 dm1 = null;
        DataMore2 dm2 = null;

        var list =
            this.Session.QueryOver<Data>()
                .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore1, () => dm1, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", 0))
                .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore2, () => dm2, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", 0))
                .Select(p =>
                    new DataQueryResult
                    {
                        PlantID = p.PlantID,
                        AreaID = p.AreaID,
                        CellID = p.CellID,
                        DeviceID = p.DeviceID,
                        StartDateTime = p.StartDateTime,
                        DataPoint01 = p.DataPoint01,
                        DataMore1Segment = dm1.Segment,
                        DataMore1DataPoint101 = dm1.DataPoint101,
                        DataMore2Segment = dm2.Segment,
                        DataMore2DataPoint201 = dm2.DataPoint201
                    })
                .List<DataQueryResult>();

        return list;   
    }
}

public class DataQueryResult
{
    internal DataQueryResult() { }

    public int PlantID { get; internal set; }
    public int AreaID { get; internal set; }
    public int CellID { get; internal set; }
    public int DeviceID { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; internal set; }
    public float DataPoint01 { get; internal set; }
    public byte? DataMore1Segment { get; internal set; }
    public float? DataMore1DataPoint101 { get; internal set; }
    public byte? DataMore2Segment { get; internal set; }
    public float? DataMore2DataPoint201 { get; internal set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractQueryObject<TResult> : IQueryObject<TResult>
{
    protected ISession Session;

    public void Configure(object parameter)
    {
        /*obviously this NH query object implementation has to be provided with an ISession before it executes.
          for that purpose I have an generic repository which holds an ISession and exposes the method
          public interface IRepository { .. TResult ExecuteQuery<TResult>(IQueryObject<TResult> query); .. }
          and has the usual Save<T>/Delete<T> methods.
          obviously, to get the results you use: var data = repository.ExecuteQuery(new DataQuery());
          i like this pattern a lot, so forgive my promotion :)
          now, one repo instance keeps alive its session, so all entities from it are from the same isession. 
          when you dispose the repo, you kill the session. if you use DI in your classes, the repo instance is injected.
          very perky is that your classes depend on the iqo and irepo ifcs which means you can swap them for EF which sometimes we do:)
          easy unit testing.. etc.. */

        if (!(parameter is ISession))
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument of wrong type.");

        this.Session = parameter as ISession;
    }

    public abstract TResult GetResult();
}

public interface IQueryObject<TResult>
{
    void Configure(object parameter);

    TResult GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Great! now i have a clue how to move forward. My hope was to reduce selects to a single select statement. I'm looking forward to giving this a go.

Comment: Getting an InvalidOperationException at runtime ... variable 'p' of type 'MyType' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Comment: Was able to get past "not defined" error with the new answer I added. Now I get a runtime error that dm1 and dm2 are null. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This modification to the accepted answer got me where I wanted to go.   The result is a single select statement that returns just what i need...

```
var list = session.QueryOver<Data>()
                            .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore1, () => dm1, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", (byte)0))
                            .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore2, () => dm2, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", (byte)0))
                            .List<Data>()
                            });
```